# Drone error: Login Failed. User limit reached

Tags: drone.io

Recently, some colleagues have started working in my team, so I showed them the basics of drone, but when they wanted to access our drone server they get that message:

```
Login Failed. User limit reached
```

We login via Github and they have access to the repositories. In fact, one of them did commit something which run the job without any problems, he just could not see it as he could not login. Any ideas on why does he get that message? I have checked our configuration and it doesn’t seem to have any limit to the number of users on drone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I reached the limits of the trial license.

I checked the limits of my current license at the /varz URL (eg. https://cloud.drone.io/varz)

Also, about the users seats and repos: https://docs.drone.io/enterprise/usage/